# Social buttons get block after installing SSL

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, google-plus, facebook-social-plugins

I just installed an SSL Certificate on my domain. and then I noticed that Social buttons (Facebook, Google+, Twitter etc) are no more there.
When I uninstalled the SLL, those buttons were there.

Anybody knows how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on cfrick's answer, which sounds spot on:

It isn't that they reject the content that isn't secure, it is that they reject mixed content. So you can't show secure and non-secure stuff on the same page.

The solution is that for any fully qualified URLs with a protocol prefix (http or https), simply leave that off and modern browsers will use the same protocol as the page was loaded with. So instead of including content with `http://example.com/stuff.js` you can use `//example.com/stuff.js`.

Answer (score 2):

most likely your code for the buttons refers to a non-SSL (http:// instead of https://) URL and most browsers nowadays reject content that is not "secure".